# ImageView scroll up and down

Tags: android

Rotate the View when i scroll up and down based on user scrolling in android,its working scrool down perfectly on `OnScrollChanged` listener but when i scroll up scroll down is always executing.

here is the code

```
iv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

                x = (int) event.getRawX();
                y = (int) event.getRawY();

                ///// working only down side

                //       rotate(120);


                Log.d("MainActivity", "before x scroll " + x);
                Log.d("MainActivity", "before y scroll " + y);

                switch (event.getAction()) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
                                view.getLayoutParams();

                        int x2= (int) event.getX();
                        int y2= (int) event.getY();


                        Log.d("MainActivity", "scroll ACTION_DOWN x scroll " + x2);
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "scroll ACTION_DOWN y scroll " + y2);



                        xDelta = x - lParams.leftMargin;
                        yDelta = y - lParams.topMargin;


                        Log.d("MainActivity", "ACTION_DOWN x scroll " + xDelta);
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "ACTION_DOWN y scroll " + yDelta);

                        rotateDown();


                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                        Log.d("MainActivity", "ACTION_UP ");


                        int x3= (int) event.getX();
                        int y3= (int) event.getY();


                        Log.d("MainActivity", "scroll ACTION_UP x scroll " + x3);
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "scroll ACTION_UP y scroll " + y3);


                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams uParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
                                view.getLayoutParams();


                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                "thanks for new location!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();

                        rotateUp();

                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view
                                .getLayoutParams();

                        int windowWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
                        int windowHeightr = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
                        layoutParams.leftMargin = x - xDelta;
                        layoutParams.topMargin = y - yDelta;

                        layoutParams.rightMargin = 0;
                        layoutParams.bottomMargin = 0;


                        if (layoutParams.leftMargin < iv.getWidth()) {
                          //  Log.d("MainActivity", "left bound reached");
                            layoutParams.leftMargin = 10;
                        }

                        if (layoutParams.topMargin < iv.getHeight()) {
                           // Log.d("MainActivity", "top bound reached");
                            layoutParams.topMargin = 10;
                        }

                        boolean collision = checkCollision(iv, bot_iv);
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "collision :" + collision);


                        if (collision) {
                            iv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        } else {
                            Log.d("MainActivity", "not collided");

                        }


                        Log.d("MainActivity", "ACTION_MOVE x scroll " + layoutParams.leftMargin);
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "ACTION_MOVE y scroll " + layoutParams.topMargin);
                        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        break;
                }
                mainLayout.invalidate();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: You must use ACTION_POINTER_UP and ACTION_POINTER_DOWN  case of MotionEvent.

Comment: not working,can u please provide the link